# UITableViewCell don't clip content horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to have a table view with `clipsToBounds` set to `YES` and allow for UITableViewCells to have parts of its contents protruding from left and right of the cell?

Comment: What type of content have you put in the cell? Did you do that programmatically or with a nib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, either the whole thing is clipped or none of it is. What you can do is have the table view in a parent view that is as tall as it needs to be and as wide as the screen, and set that to clip.

[image]